# Error in button

Tags: java, arraylist, counter

I need to create these 2 arraylists so i can compare them and if they are the same as each other than intCorrect += 1

Do you guys see anything wrong with my code because i keep on getting an error saying it can't find strArrayQuestion nor intCounter.

```
public class Grade9Application extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private ArrayList<String> strArrayAnswer;  
private ArrayList<String> strArrayQuestion;
int intCorrect = 0;

private void btnPage1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //removing panel
    pnlMain.removeAll();
    pnlMain.repaint();
    pnlMain.revalidate();        
    //adding panels
    pnlMain.add(pnlPage1);
    pnlMain.repaint();
    pnlMain.revalidate();        
}                                        

private void btnPage2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //removing panel
    pnlMain.removeAll();
    pnlMain.repaint();
    pnlMain.revalidate();        
    //adding panels
    pnlMain.add(pnlPage2);
    pnlMain.repaint();
    pnlMain.revalidate();  
}                                        

private void btnPage3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //removing panel
    pnlMain.removeAll();
    pnlMain.repaint();
    pnlMain.revalidate();        
    //adding panels
    pnlMain.add(pnlPage3);
    pnlMain.repaint();
    pnlMain.revalidate();  
}                                        

private void btnPage4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //removing panel
    pnlMain.removeAll();
    pnlMain.repaint();
    pnlMain.revalidate();        
    //adding panels
    pnlMain.add(pnlPage4);
    pnlMain.repaint();
    pnlMain.revalidate();

    String strQ1,strQ2,strQ3,strQ4,strQ5,strQ6,strQ7,strQ8,strQ9,strQ10;
    strQ1 = "Perfume evaporating on your skin";
    strQ2 = "butter melting";
    strQ3 = "wood rotting";
    strQ4 = "charcoal heating a grill";
    strQ5 = "autumn leaves changing color";
    strQ6 = "a hot glass cracking when placed in cold water";
    strQ7 = "melting copper metal" ;      
    strQ8 = "burning sugar";
    strQ9 = "mixing sugar in water ";
    strQ10 = "digesting food";

    this.lblQ1.setText(strQ1);
    this.lblQ2.setText(strQ2);
    this.lblQ3.setText(strQ3);
    this.lblQ4.setText(strQ4);
    this.lblQ5.setText(strQ5);
    this.lblQ6.setText(strQ6);
    this.lblQ7.setText(strQ7);
    this.lblQ8.setText(strQ8);
    this.lblQ9.setText(strQ9);
    this.lblQ10.setText(strQ10);


    String strA1, strA2, strA3, strA4, strA5, strA6, strA7, strA8, strA9, strA10;
    strA1 = this.txtInputA1.getText();
    strA2 = this.txtInputA2.getText();
    strA3 = this.txtInputA3.getText();
    strA4 = this.txtInputA4.getText();
    strA5 = this.txtInputA5.getText();
    strA6 = this.txtInputA6.getText();
    strA7 = this.txtInputA7.getText();
    strA8 = this.txtInputA8.getText();
    strA9 = this.txtInputA9.getText();
    strA10 = this.txtInputA10.getText();

    strArrayQuestion.add(strA1);
    strArrayQuestion.add(strA2);
    strArrayQuestion.add(strA3);
    strArrayQuestion.add(strA4);
    strArrayQuestion.add(strA5);
    strArrayQuestion.add(strA6);
    strArrayQuestion.add(strA7);      
    strArrayQuestion.add(strA8);
    strArrayQuestion.add(strA9);
    strArrayQuestion.add(strA10);  

    strArrayAnswer.add("physical");
    strArrayAnswer.add("physical");
    strArrayAnswer.add("chemical");
    strArrayAnswer.add("chemical");
    strArrayAnswer.add("chemical");
    strArrayAnswer.add("physical");
    strArrayAnswer.add("physical");
    strArrayAnswer.add("chemical");
    strArrayAnswer.add("physical");
    strArrayAnswer.add("chemical");

    for (int i = 0; i < strArrayAnswer.size()-1; i++){
        if(strArrayAnswer.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(strArrayQuestion.get(i))){
            intCorrect += 1;
        }
    }
}                                        

private void btnpage5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //removing panel
    pnlMain.removeAll();
    pnlMain.repaint();
    pnlMain.revalidate();        
    //adding panels
    pnlMain.add(pnlPage5);
    pnlMain.repaint();
    pnlMain.revalidate();  
}                                        

private void btnExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    System.exit(0);
}                                       

private void btnDoneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    //removing panel
    pnlMain.removeAll();
    pnlMain.repaint();
    pnlMain.revalidate();        
    //adding panels
    pnlMain.add(pnlPage5);
    pnlMain.repaint();
    pnlMain.revalidate();  

    System.out.println(intCorrect);
}
```

Edit:Updated Code

Comment: `ArrayList(i)` should be `ArrayList.get(i)`...

Comment: ohhh i get it, no pun intended. But how come intCounter still can't be found?

Comment: @JefferyCao you haven't declared it anywhere...

Comment: You have `intCorrect` not `intCounter` declared at the top...

Comment: omg i'm sorry i havn't slept in 24 hours...

Comment: Go sleep. You will have a clearer mind.

Comment: How come i keep getting a java.lang.NullPointerException error when i click my btnPage4

Comment: The ArrayLists haven't been initialized? And the main panel?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to stop right now to look at your code and see what can be refactored. This will make your program so much simpler. You can create a Question class like this...

```
public class Question {
    String question;
    String answer;

public Question(String question, String answer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
}

//getter and setter methods

}
```

Next you would want to create  `Arraylist<Question> questions;` inside of your application to hold your questions. Then you can create `Arraylist<String> userAnswers;` to hold user answers. Lastly create a for loop to compare your users answers against the question answers

```
for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) {
    if (questions.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(userAnswers.get(i))) {
        intCorrect++;
    }
}
```

Ideally for growing an application I would adopt this structure, but if you just need a simple way to get this done that is still easy to understand you could bypass creating `Arraylist userAnswers;` and implement this version of the Question class...

```
public class Question {
    String question;
    String correctAnswer;
    String userAnswer;


public Question(String question, String answer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
}

public boolean isUserCorrect() {
    if (correctAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(userAnswer)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//getter and setter methods

}
```

set the user answer value on the question object

```
questions.get(0).setUserAnswer("physical");
```

then run an enhanced for loop to increment your intCorrect value.

```
for (Question questions: question) {
    if (question.isUserCorrect()) {
        intCorrect++;
    }
}
```

Comment: uhh could you explain to me a bit more on how to implement the classes

Comment: Sorry i'm still fairly new to this. How can i create a new class cause every time i try to i get a syntax error

Comment: currently you are using something called parallel arrays (ex: question(1) is related to answer(1)), instead of using parallel arrays you can use the question class to relate questions to answers.
to create your questions you could do
Arraylist<Question> questions = new Arraylist<Question>();
questions.add(new Question("Perfume evaporating on your skin", "physical"));

do that for each question, then for setting each label you can do lblQ1.setText(questions.get(0).getQuestion());
and so on for each question.

lastly for each user question you can do 
questions.get(0).setUserAnswer(strA1); 
etc.

Comment: Oh okay how come intCorrect keeps returning as 0 though in my code, shouldn't it still work even though it's not as neat?

Comment: as long as the text is spelled exactly the same it looks like it should work, but there is one error I see. I believe inside your loop the code "strArrayAnswer.size() - 1" is supposed to be "strArrayAnswer.size()". If you dont change it you will only ever process 9 of the 10 questions

Comment: i thought since index's start from 0 putting the -1 there means it will process questions in the index 0-9

Comment: the < symbol will ensure you only go to 9. If the size is 10 whenever i < 10, i=9 will pass the condition and enter the loop, but the next iteration, i=10, will fail. This means that the loop will only ever be ran until i is equal to 9. if you did the -1 then it would pass at i=8 but fail when i=9 because 9 is not < 9. If you would change your logic to <= then it would be correct, but in its current state it is incorrect.